# javafx: How do I create a TreeItem that displays a tooltip that contains the file path and load the file path on double click?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to attach a tooltip, which contains the file path, to the `TreeItem<String>`, such that when I hover around this TreeItem, it will display a text of the file path when I hover my mouse around it. This does not work in my code, as it complains I cannot install this on to a String. How can I solve this problem?

Second, I want to be able to double click on the TreeItem then it can automatically load the file. How can I achieve that ?

```
    @FXML
    TreeView<String> fxFileTree;
    public void defineFileTree(){
        TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Portfolio");
        fxFileTree.setShowRoot(true);
        root.setExpanded(true);
        fxFileTree.setRoot(root);
    }

    public void populateTree(String fileName, String filePath){
        addLeaf(fileName, (TreeItem<String>) fxFileTree.getRoot(), filePath);
    }

    public void addLeaf(String leaf, TreeItem<String> parent, String filePath{
        TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>(leaf);
        Tooltip.install(item,filepath)       // <- This is wrong
        parent.getChildren().add(item);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** the goal of this exercise is to build a tree which only contains the root and one level of branches, i.e. `root -> leaf1` (stop here,no grandchildren for root, children only). The root will just be a title String. And I want to add leaves to the root. The leaf is a file object. The display text of the leaf will be the file name and install the tooltip for this leaf. The tooltip will show the file path.

Comment: [`TreeItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeItem.html) doesn't have an `install` method: it's not really clear what method you intend to call there, or what you think that will do. To install a tooltip, or to handle mouse events, you need to use the `TreeCell`, so you should set a [`cellFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html#cellFactoryProperty) on your `TreeView`. (Also, if your `TreeView` is displaying files, you probably want a `TreeView<File>` or `TreeView<Path>`, instead of a `TreeView<String>`.)

Comment: My bad. I copied and pasted the wrong code. it should be `Tooltip.install(...)`, as I was trying to install tooltip to the `TreeItem`.

Comment: OK, that makes (a little) more sense. But still, [`Tooltip.install(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#install-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-) expects a `Node` and a `Tooltip`: a `TreeItem` is not a `Node` (and a `String` is not a `Tooltip`). You need to set the tooltip on the `TreeCell` (which has a `setTooltip(...)` method), as described in my first comment.

Comment: I just updated my question to give readers more info. Hopefully, this makes a bit sense as to what I am trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a tooltip on a `TreeItem`. `TreeItem`s represent the *data* displayed in a tree, they are not UI components. You need to set the tooltip on the `TreeCell`s, which you can do in a factory.

Since you are going to need access to the data about the file, you should not be using `TreeView<String>` and `TreeItem<String>`: you should either use `TreeView<File>` or `TreeView<Path>` (in other words, make the data type of the tree either [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)). So you would do something like:

```
@FXML
private TreeView<Path> fxFileTree ;

private TreeItem<Path> root ;

// ...

public void initialize() {
    fxFileTree.setCellFactory(tv ->  {
        final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        TreeCell<Path> cell = new TreeCell<Path>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Path item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setTooltip(null);
                } else if (getTreeItem() == root) {
                    setText("Portfolio");
                    setTooltip(null);
                } else {
                    setText(item.getFileName().toString());
                    tooltip.setText(item.toRealPath().toString());
                    setTooltip(tooltip);
                }
            }
        };
        cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && ! cell.isEmpty()) {
                Path file = cell.getItem();
                // do whatever you need with path...
            }
        });
        return cell ;
    });
}


public void defineFileTree(){
    root = new TreeItem<>(null);
    fxFileTree.setShowRoot(true);
    root.setExpanded(true);
    fxFileTree.setRoot(root);
}

// ...
```

Comment: I would like to know if I change the name of the treecell, how can this automatically change the name of the file name itself as well ?

Comment: Sorry, I know this is probably another question.

Comment: Using your code above, I do not know how to define my root with a display text "Portfolio", as the tree only accepts Path object now.

Comment: `TreeView` is kind of a pain because all the `TreeItem`s have to have the same type. So you cannot have a `TreeItem<String>` with `TreeItem<Path>` as children. Your two options are to either make this a `TreeView<Object>` and do lots of ugly downcasting, or set the root `TreeItem`'s value to `null` and treat it as a special case in the cell factory. I updated the code with the second idea. I wonder though, if a `TreeView` is the correct control to use here. Perhaps a `TitledPane` containing a `ListView` would work better.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your other comment: are you asking about making the cells editable? That sounds like a different question anyway; I would get this working first then ask that if you still can't get that part working.

Comment: Yep. I am considering using listview as well